# Why sections in the minitoc are not bold?

Tags: fonts, tocloft, minitoc

Everything is in the question...

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book}
% 
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
\usepackage[francais]{minitoc}  
\usepackage[section]{placeins}  
\usepackage{titletoc}%
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft}

% remove chapters number
\counterwithout{section}{chapter}
% num depth of toc
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
% depth of toc
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
% minitoc
\setcounter{minitocdepth}{2}    
% add dots
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
% add chapter
\newlength\mylength
\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{\chaptername~}
\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnum{~~-~~}
\settowidth\mylength{\cftchappresnum\cftchapaftersnum\quad}
\addtolength\cftchapnumwidth{\mylength}

\begin{document}
\dominitoc
\tableofcontents
\chapter{blablabla}
\minitoc
\section{myfirstsection}
\subsection{blabla}
\section{mysecondsection}
\subsection{blabla} 
\end{document}
```

I've also try to add this but does not affect the result :

```
\setlength{\mtcindent}{24pt}
\renewcommand{\mtcfont}{\small\rm}
\renewcommand{\mtcSfont}{\small\bf}
```

---

[image]

Sorry in advance for my poor english !

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this :
There is a bad interaction between the minitoc and tocloft packages
so I have:

```
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\small\bfseries}
```

the complete code :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book}
% 
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
\usepackage[francais]{minitoc}  
\usepackage[section]{placeins}  
\usepackage{titletoc}%
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft}

% remove chapters number
\counterwithout{section}{chapter}
% num depth of toc
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
% depth of toc
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
% minitoc
\setcounter{minitocdepth}{2}    
% add dots
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
% add chapter
\newlength\mylength
\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{\chaptername~}
\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnum{~~-~~}
\settowidth\mylength{\cftchappresnum\cftchapaftersnum\quad}
\addtolength\cftchapnumwidth{\mylength}

\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\small\bfseries}
%\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\small\bfseries}



\begin{document}
\dominitoc
\tableofcontents
\chapter{blablabla}
\minitoc
\section{myfirstsection}
\subsection{blabla}
\section{mysecondsection}
\subsection{blabla} 
\end{document}
```

[image]